# Ubuntu 18.04.3 doesn't support Logitech MX Anywhere Bluetooth Mouse

Tags: 18.04, mouse, bluetooth, xps, logitech

I have a [Logitech MX Anywhere 2](https://www.logitech.com/en-us/manuals/11892#section1) Bluetooth mouse on a Dell [XPS 13 9343](https://www.dell.com/support/search/us/en/04#q=XPS%2013%209343&sort=relevancy&f:langFacet=[en]), running 18.04.3 LTS. I can't get the mouse to connect.

I've run:

- power on
- power off
- scan on
- connnect / pair MAC Address

But I just get these errors:

> Failed to connect: org.bluez.ErrorFailed" or Failed to connect: org.bluez.ErrorAuthenticationFailed

I'm not sure what else to try.

EDIT:

> cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep "model name" && sudo lshw | grep -A5 "Moth" && lshw | grep product

```
model name  : Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-5200U CPU @ 2.20GHz 
       description: Motherboard
       product: 0TM99H
       vendor: Dell Inc.
       physical id: 0
       version: A00
WARNING: you should run this program as super-user.
          product: Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-5200U CPU @ 2.20GHz
          product: Broadwell-U Host Bridge -OPI
             product: HD Graphics 5500
             product: Broadwell-U Audio Controller
             product: Broadwell-U Processor Thermal Subsystem
             product: Wildcat Point-LP USB xHCI Controller
             product: Wildcat Point-LP MEI Controller #1
             product: Wildcat Point-LP High Definition Audio Controller
             product: Wildcat Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #1
                product: RTS5249 PCI Express Card Reader
             product: Wildcat Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #4
                product: BCM4352 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter
             product: Wildcat Point-LP USB EHCI Controller
             product: Wildcat Point-LP LPC Controller
             product: Wildcat Point-LP SATA Controller [AHCI Mode]
             product: Wildcat Point-LP SMBus Controller
             product: Wildcat Point-LP Thermal Management Controller
```

Comment: Hey, I added the info you asked about.

Comment: Batman, thank you! Nothing found in Dell's Support https://www.dell.com/support/search/us/en/04#q=XPS%2013%209343%20Ubuntu&sort=relevancy&f:langFacet=[en] or at Logitech https://support.logi.com/hc/en-us/search#q=Ubuntu%20MX%20Anywhere&s=all , will look further when I can.

Comment: It's okay. I've solved the issue by finding the correct bluetooth driver on github, thank you

Comment: What driver? Please answer your question with that link, and an explanation.

Comment: @Batman the point of this Q&A site is to solve your problem while solving possible future ones. What did it solve for you?

Answer (score 0):

I had initially also problems in conjunction with a newer **Logitech MX Anywhere 3** mouse (Mac version) under **Kubuntu 20.04 LTS** (kernel 5.13.0-41-generic).

Regardless what I tried, the mouse didn't connect when I want to pair it via the **Bluetooth assistant** in KDE plasma. Then I decided to connect the mouse via the USB cable. At first this didn't change anything, the mouse just started to load its battery.

However, I then tried again to pair the mouse via the "pairing button" (pushed it for more than 5 seconds) and simply select at the BT icon on the taskbar (right clicked on it) the "connect" option. And for whatever reason it worked that time. The Logitech MX Anywhere 3 mouse works perfectly well. There was nothing to adjust, the sensitivity and reaction time suits perfectly well and also the scroll wheel works as it should (it is not inverted, even on the Mac version of that mouse).

Final note, the **proprietary Logitech transmitter** (which comes as an USB dongle) is known to work under Linux almost always right out of the box. So this may be the alternative solution for using this mouse under Linux. Note, the Mac version of the Logitech MX Anywhere 3 doesn't include that Logitech transmitter. It has to be purchased additionally.

Warning, the Logitech MX Anywhere 3 is **BT LE** (aka BT 4.x) only. It doesn't work with legacy BT 2.x and BT 3.x controllers.