# Bluetooth not syncing with Logitech MX Anywhere 3 mouse after upgrade too 21.04 from 20.10 on HP255G5 laptop. Help?

Tags: upgrade, bluetooth, mouse, 21.04, logitech

I am new to Ubuntu 21.04 after upgrading from 20.10. I am trying to pair my Logitech MX Anywhere 3 Bluetooth mouse and sometimes see a list of devices inluding it and sometimes not. Regardless, when I see the mouse listed to pair, requesting the pairing fails every time. I have updated Bluez and even created a new config file for the mouse yet nothing seems to work.
This began not immediately after the upgrade but after the last kernel update.
I see that several other people are having very similar problems with various Bluetooth devices on different hardware. Can anyone offer us all some help solving this problem?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. Somehow the pairing process seems to be broken in the user interface.

After trying many things, I found out that pairing with the `bluetoothctl` command line tool worked.

Start `bluetoothctl`

```
❯ sudo bluetoothctl
Agent registered
```

List devices

```
[MX Anywhere 3]# devices
Device 12:34:56:78:9A:BC MX Anywhere 3
```

Disconnect, just to make sure

```
[MX Anywhere 3]# disconnect
Attempting to disconnect from 12:34:56:78:9A:BC
Successful disconnected
[CHG] Device 12:34:56:78:9A:BC Connected: no
```

Pair the mouse via hardware address

```
[bluetooth]# pair 12:34:56:78:9A:BC
Attempting to pair with 12:34:56:78:9A:BC
[CHG] Device 12:34:56:78:9A:BC Connected: yes
Request authorization
```

Accept the pairing by typing "yes"

```
[agent] Accept pairing (yes/no): yes
[CHG] Device 12:34:56:78:9A:BC Paired: yes
Pairing successful
[CHG] Device 12:34:56:78:9A:BC Appearance: 0x03c2
[CHG] Device 12:34:56:78:9A:BC Icon: input-mouse
[CHG] Device 12:34:56:78:9A:BC Modalias: usb:v046DpB025d0015
[CHG] Device 12:34:56:78:9A:BC ServicesResolved: yes
```

From here on, the mouse worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

This answer was originally posted [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1165540/ubuntu-18-04-3-doesnt-support-logitech-mx-anywhere-bluetooth-mouse) but it should be helpful also with this question.

**Update**: There seems to exist in newer Ubuntu versions a **BlueZ** v5.62 & v5.63 (Linux Bluetooth protocol stack) related [issue](https://github.com/bluez/bluez/issues/220) with certain Logitech BT LE mouses. This should be fixed in BlueZ **v5.64**. And alternatively a downgrade to v5.61 may also help.

Note, the following information is BlueZ v5.53 related:

I had initially also problems in conjunction with a **Logitech MX Anywhere 3** mouse (Mac version) under **Kubuntu 20.04 LTS** (kernel 5.13.0-41-generic).

Regardless what I tried, the mouse didn't connect when I want to pair it via the **Bluetooth assistant** in KDE plasma. Then I decided to connect the mouse via the USB cable. At first this didn't change anything, the mouse just started to load its battery.

However, I then tried again to pair the mouse via the "pairing button" (pushed it for more than 5 seconds) and simply select at the BT icon on the taskbar (right clicked on it) the "connect" option. And for whatever reason it worked that time. The Logitech MX Anywhere 3 mouse works perfectly well. There was nothing to adjust, the sensitivity and reaction time suits perfectly well and also the scroll wheel works as it should (it is not inverted, even on the Mac version of that mouse).

Final note, the **proprietary Logitech transmitter** (which comes as an USB dongle) is known to work under Linux almost always right out of the box. So this may be the alternative solution for using this mouse under Linux. Note, the Mac version of the Logitech MX Anywhere 3 doesn't include that Logitech transmitter. It has to be purchased additionally.

Warning, the Logitech MX Anywhere 3 is **BT LE** (aka BT 4.x) only. It doesn't work with legacy BT 2.x and BT 3.x controllers.